# compute Invested Capital for banks on finance.yahoo . .

Tags: banking, yahoo-finance

My question is about the calculation of Invested Capital on finance.yahoo.com . . . and in particular the calculation of this metric for banks.

On finance.yahoo, under Financials > Balance Sheet, you will find the Invested Capital metric for most funds. Now you can blindly copy that metric, but I like to understand how that is calculated.

At Yahoo, the general rule for Invested Capital is:

Invested Capital = CurrentDebt +  LongTermDebt + Stockholders Equity excl Minority

Below I give a screenshot for Coca-Cola as an example:
For example, for year-end 2021, this is:

65,760 = 4,645 + 38,116 + 22,999

However... This is calculated differently at banks. And that makes sense, because a bank is not an "ordinary" company.

For example, if I look at ABN-Amro, I do not come up with the Invested Capital (year-end 2021) of EUR 89,231 indicated by Yahoo

The general formula is EUR 485 lower

89,716 = 0 + 67,722 + 21,994 (there is no CurrentDebt hence "0")

THEREFORE... Something is being corrected somewhere, but I can't figure out which posts

Therefore, my QUESTION . . .

- is there a link where exactly it is explained how it is calculated
- or does someone know how Invested Capital for banks is calculated

[screenshot ABN Amro and CocaCola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajYYN.png)

ABN-Amro: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABN.AS/balance-sheet?p=ABN.AS

Coca-Coca: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/KO/balance-sheet?p=KO